# How i can edit and save data to core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data

My Data Model.
[image: Data model]

And I have 3 pages.

**page 1** show all courses in a tableview. When a course is selected all the students on that course are shown an a tableview on page 2.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
    Coures *course =[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    ScoreViewController *scoreView =[[ScoreViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScoreViewController" bundle:nil];
    scoreView.title =course.courseID;
    scoreView.scoreData=course.scores;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:scoreView animated:YES];
    [scoreView release];
}
```

**page 2** shows a tableview that lists all students on a particular. When a row containing a student is touched the student's name and score is shown on page 3.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    DetailViewController *detailviewController =[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    NSArray *scoreArray =[self.scoreData allObjects];
    Score *score =(Score *)[scoreArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailviewController animated:YES];
    detailviewController.rescore =score;
    [detailviewController release];
}
```

**page 3** Shows the student's name and score in text fields.

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

    rescore.score=[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[scoreField.text doubleValue]];
    NSError *error;
    [[rescore managedObjectContext] save:&error];
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
```

I want to edit the student's name and score on the third page, but when I go back to the second page from the 3rd page, the new score is not saved.

Answer (score 1):

You must create a class for each object, called a managed object class. After doing so, you just alter that object's attributes and your core data model will get updated.

Comment: i already created the managed object class call score,student and course.

Comment: Then, just alter that object's attributes. Your model will get updated.

Comment: if i edit rescore.forstuden.name =@"SomeName" it work! but for [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[scoreField.text doubleValue]]; it not work.(rescore.score is NSnumber)

Comment: You're adding a doubleValue to NSNumber. Make them both the same type.

Comment: i create data model score as double

Comment: It doesn't matter. Core Data object models store values as NSNumber objects. You need to typecast back into a double value if you want to use it. Something like this `[score.points doubleValue]`